# A minimal semigroup generating subset of the additive reals

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, vector-spaces

I asked this [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498883/is-there-a-minimal-generating-set-of-reals-which-additively-generate-all-the-rea), but I was told to ask it here because it is a difficult question. Consider the additive magma of the real numbers, $(\mathbb{R};+)$. Does there exist a subset $S$ of the reals which additively generates the reals, but such that no proper subset of $S$ additively generates the reals?

(Alex Kruckman [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4513877/28111) that there is not a minimal subset generating the *group* of reals under addition, but that answers a weaker question; separately, Keith Kearnes [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4529488/28111) some obstacles to the question as phrased.)

Comment: I've added a link and a bit of context.

Comment: I think second paragraph is that he showed there is **no** minimal subset...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Whoops, fixed!

Comment: @bof: The answer is negative for (ℚ,+). If ⊆ℚ existed, each element of  could be isolated from the others by a maximal subsemigroup (∀∈ ∃ maximal ≤ℚ such that −={}). But the only maximal subsemigroups of (ℚ,+) are [0,∞) and (−∞,0]. Altogether this means that (ℚ,+) is not finitely generated, so any irredundant generating subset would have to be infinite, but there aren't enough maximal subsemigroups to isolate each element of an infinite subset from the others in that set.

Comment: It's a question about semigroups, nothing serious to do with general magmas.

Comment: That a nonzero divisible abelian group has no minimal generating subset is quite immediate; e.g., the argument can be found in the proof of Proposition 4.11 in my 2014 J. Inst. Math. Jussieu paper with Bieri, Guyot and Strebel [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0271) — I also reproduced it [at the MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4531949/35400).

Comment: The argument for nonzero divisible abelian groups appears at the foot of page 462 of 'Abelian groups possessing irreducible systems of generators' by Alexander Soifer, Siberian Mathematical Journal volume 12, pages 461-468 (1971).

Comment: Let $V$ be the $\aleph_0$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$. It seems to me that the additive semigroup of $\mathbb R$ has an irredundant generating set iff the additive semigroup of $V$ has an irredundant generating set. Have I got that right?

Comment: @bof: I see one direction, but not the other. If $S$ is an irredundant generating set for $V$ (considered as a semigroup), then $\oplus^{\kappa} S$ is an irredundant generating subset for $\oplus^{\kappa} V$ (considered as a semigroup). This shows how to go up in dimension: If the $\aleph_0$-dimensional rational vector space has an irredundant $+$-generating subset, then all infinite-dimensional rational vector spaces have irredundant $+$-generating subsets. But how do you bring the dimension down?

Comment: @KeithKearnes Suppose $S$ is an irredundant generating set for the additive semigroup of $\mathbb R$. Now construct sequences $V_0\subset V_1\subset\cdots$ and $S_0\subset S_1\subset\cdots$ so that $V_n$ is an $\aleph_0$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$, $S_n$ is a countable subset of $S$, and $V_n\subset\langle S_n\rangle\subset V_{n+1}$. Then $\bigcup_nS_n$ is an irredundant generating set for $\bigcup_nV_n$. Right?

Comment: @bof: Ok, I agree.

Comment: @KeithKearnes In that case I guess the problem is best considered in the setting of that countable semigroup. We can forget about Zorn's lemma and the axiom of choice, as all the needed nonconstructivity has gone into showing the equivalence.